# Low validation accuracy after mobilenet transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow

I need a tensorflow model which recognizes a dog's breed. I downloaded the Stanford Dogs Dataset - 20,580 images in 120 categories (=breeds). I followed the procedure described in *TensorFlow For Poets* to retrain mobilenet_1.0_224. I used *--how_many_training_steps=4000* and defaults for everything else. I got this tensorboard graph:
[Training and validation accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZmE6.png)

The validation accuracy is only about 80%.

What can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

In the research paper [MobileNets: Efficient Convolutional Neural Networks for Mobile Vision Applications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf), the test accuracy using the 'MobileNet_1.0_224' architecture on the Stanford Dogs dataset is 83.3%, which seems in line with your results.

When you visually examine the Stanford Dogs Dataset you will find a lot of the breeds look similar, which makes it hard to reach a higher accuracy, even with the state of the art image classifiers in accuracy. You might improve your results by either splitting similar looking breeds into larger subcategories.

Alternatively, you might tweak the training settings of the retrain.py script in the Tensorflow for Poets tutorial, but the gains will be likely be marginal.

Comment: After cropping the input images with this script
https://github.com/AbdullahWali/ImageNet-Bounding-Box-Crop-Tool/blob/master/cropImages.py
the validation accuracy increased to around 83%